# How to use Redis with Firebase Functions?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a NodeJS app on Firebase Functions but I don't know how to use some caching system like Redis with it.

Comment: You need to set up a Serverless VPC Access (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options) to access the Redis server (or Memorystore service)

Answer (score 2):

- You can use package [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache)
- or you can check [Connecting to a Redis instance from Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-functions)